# How can I measure the performance of a Java program?

Tags: java, trace

How can I trace a Java program performance? Example, how long each method takes? How many resources were used and so on? I need some info for me to work on optimizing my Java program.

Comment: http://slashdot.org/story/06/06/30/0053237/Java-Profilers---Which-One-Are-You-Using

Answer (score 2):

As others previously mentioned, profilers are the go. A long time ago, I'd used http://www.yourkit.com/, and found it quite easy to use and informative.

If you are keen, you could investigate using AOP for method timing etc. Just search Google for AOP method timing for some ideas.

Comment: It's been many years since I last tried JProfiler, so it may very well be that it is worth a shot. Last time I used it, it was free, and if this is still the case, it would be good to try this over something like YourKit that you have to pay for as you may find that JProfiler does the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening your project in Netbeans, from there you can use the Profiler tool and get performance data for methods, load times, etc. It's really easy to use and the data is very complete.

[Netbeans Profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a JVM profiling tool such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Making a good and robust benchmark in java is hard. Take a look at the following articles:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In optimizing, it's hard to tell what causes the slow performance. Usually a bad algorithm (complexity) causes it. Maybe you can start from the algorithm first before go into further detail tweak

Comment: I was thinking of having a way to tell me where have I done a bad algorithm.